# MVC3 RC Razor @helper locations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In the introduction to Razor on [ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx), he mentioned placing the `@helper`s inside `Views\Helpers`. I tried doing so in the RC and after a lot of searching, I found out that the helpers should be in the `App_Code` folder. I don't *need* my helpers in another assembly (especially if they're specific to *this* project), and having them way up in the `App_Code` seems ugly IMO. Is there a current solution to have the these helpers inside a `View\Helpers` folder?

Comment: ` I found out that the views should be in the App_Code folder` Say what??? Views should be placed in the `Views\\[ControllerName]\\` folder.

Comment: Sorry meant 'helpers'... It's too early in the morning :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid they didn't yet implement this feature yet, at least not in the RC build.

Comment: Do you know if it will be available for RTM?

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky, quite honestly I have no idea.

Comment: Ok thanks Darin! Hopefully @Haacked and the team will include this in the next release!

Comment: At this point it's unlikely that helpers in Views\Helpers will work in MVC 3 RTM. It was an idea that simply could not be realized for technical reasons. They will work in App_code and we will have more information about that closer to RTM

Comment: @marcind - That's too bad to hear. It really would have been nice to have these helpers within Views\Helpers. Thanks for the update though!

Answer (score 5):

Now we have detailed blog post on this issue at first-hand by Scott Gu

[ASP.NET MVC 3 and the @helper syntax within Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx)